# How to stop remounts and avoid having to lift state with React Router 5 and <Switch>?

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, router

The default behaviour for React Router 5  appears to be to remount components on each selection.  I have been lifting (routed) component state up into the router and passing in as props. This can't be right. Is there a correct way to use  to keep a component mounted so I can visit other routes at the same level and keep the state of previously mounted components?

```
        <Switch location={location}>
          <Route exact path="/">
            ...          
          </Route>
          <Route path="/another">
            ...
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

The only alternative i can think of is tabs where i keep all items mounted and use visibility to show/hide mounted objects.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to use redux.

Comment: why redux? i realise it provides single state but i think its a Router design issue that to  have to lift  state and break component encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the React Router docs...
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/children-func

Short answer: I used children prop and conditional className based on {match} to show or hide the component - with no encloseing switch (as this forces re-render).

```
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about" key="about" children={({match})=>
        <div className={match ? "show" : "hide"}>
          <About/>
        </div>}
      />     
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
```

Solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-without-remount-tenln?file=/style.css